# Parsing Through Dictionary with multiple keys correctly

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I've wrote the function to parse through my created Dictionary of abbreviations and meanings. But It wont work for longer abbreviations. I think it's finding the first instance of piece and spitting that out. I want it to take the whole input and return the value that responds to that. Single letters and double letters work mostly but longer stuff is a no go.

Example of my key:values
{'b00n': ['new person'], 'hv': ['have'], 'wuwtb': ['what do you want to talk about'], 'l8rz': ['later'], 'jhm': ['just hold me'],

```
def main():
    game = True
    myDict = CreateDictionary('textToEnglish.csv')
    print(myDict)
    while game == True:
        abbrev = input("Please enter text abbreviations seperated by comma:")
        newList = list(abbrev)
        print([v for k, v in myDict.items() if k in newList])

        answer = input("Would you like to input more abbreviations? yes(y) or no(n):")
        if answer == "y":
            game = True
        else:
            game = False
```

Comment: As an aside, you should always compare booleans with 'is', so instead of "while game == True" use "while game is True".

As a separate style note, I would suggest using "while game" instead of "while game is True", because the first is more concise (though you might argue the second is more readable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

abbrev is a string, when you turn it into a list, you're getting a list of each letter:

```
>>> abbrev = 'one, two, three'
>>> list(abbrev)
['o', 'n', 'e', ',', ' ', 't', 'w', 'o', ',', ' ', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e']
```

You may want something like this instead:

```
>>> abbrev.split(',')
['one', ' two', ' three']
```

Comment: Sounds so obvious now! Much appreciated.